# Link in div becomes inactive when placed with z-index above another div

Tags: hyperlink, z-index

I have made a 3D cube, and when you click on some element on the cube, a div (larger than the cube) is displayed on top of the cube. In this div are some links – the problem is, that the parts of the links that are exactly above the cube, doesn’t work. The parts of the links that are not above the cube (they are further to the right or left) work perfectly fine as links. I am using z-index to position the layers, and I simply can’t figure out what is wrong. If anyone has a suggestion, I would very much appreciate it.

I added my code below - it is very extensive, so I tried to leave out the elements that shouldn't be related to the issue. I don't think that the script should be the issue either, but I added the code related to the elements just in case.

Thanks

HTML:

```
<ul id="cube">
        <li class='face' id="facecubeone"></li>
        <li class='face' id="facecubetwo"></li>
        <li class='face' id="facecubethree"></li>
        <li class='face' id="facecubefour">
            <ul class="cube2 low oneleft" id="cubefour1">
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 high twoleft" id="cubefour2">
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 high threeleft activefour active" id="cubefour3">
                <li><a href="#" class='square' style="padding-top: 0px;"><img id="mig" src="img/cvbillede.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="ABOUT ME"></img></a></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 high fourleft activefour active" id="cubefour4">
                <li><a href="#" class='square'>Choko-app<img class="smallpic" id="" src="img/choko.jpg" width="100" alt="picturesoftheapp"></a></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 high fiveleft" id="cubefour5">
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 low sixleft" id="cubefour6">
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 low sevenleft" id="cubefour7">
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 high eightleft" id="cubefour8">
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cube2 high nineleft activefour active" id="cubefour9">
                <li><a href="#" class='square'>Visualization <img class="smallpic" id="" src="img/visual.jpg" width="100" alt="pictureofthesite"></a></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
                <li class='square'></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='face'></li>
        <li class='face'></li>
    </ul>

<div id="myprojects">

      <div class="projects" id="projectme">
            <a href="#"><img class="exit" src="img/exit.png" alt="exit"></img></a>
            <div class="projecttext">
                <p class="titles">About me</p>
                <p class="descriptions" id="">
                TEXT
                </p>
                <div class="links" id=""><a href="DOCUMENT.pdf" target="_blank">LINK TO RESUME - only part of it works</a><br><a href="#" target="_blank">LINK TO LINKEDIN PROFILE</a></div>    
            </div>
            <img class="projectimages" id="" src="img/cvbillede.jpg" width="310px" height="310px" alt="pictureofme"></img>
        </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cube {
position: fixed;
clear: both;
z-index: 900;
padding: 0;
width: 350px; height: 350px;
list-style: none;

/* centering */
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;

-webkit-transform: rotate3d(-10, 30, -4, 47.5deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-animation: ani 8s infinite linear; }

.cube2 {
position: relative;
/*z-index: 901;*/
float: left;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
width: 116.63px; height: 116.63px; 
list-style: none;}

.face, #face {
box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
margin: -175px;
width: 350px; height: 350px;
background: black; }

.square {
box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 0em;
width: 116.63px; height: 116.63px;
padding-top: 2.5px;
background-color: black;}

#myprojects {
clear: both;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9990;
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
    top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
display: none;}

.projects {
position: relative;
z-index: 9991;
width: 680px;
height: 380px;
padding: 10px;
display: none;

border: 2px solid black;
background: rgb(68,68,68); /* Old browsers */}

.exit { 
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
float: right;}

.projecttext {
clear: both;
position: relative;
z-index: 9992;
margin-top: 0px;
float: left;
height: 350px;
width: 370px;}

.titles {
margin-top: 0px;}

.descriptions {
margin-right: 10px;
height: 220px;
text-align: justify;}

.links a{
position: relative;
line-height: 26px;
z-index: 9999;}

.links a:hover {
}

.projectimages {
margin-top: 43px;
float: right;
width: 310px;}
```

SCRIPT:

```
    $(function(){       

var visible = false;    

    $('.exit').click(function(){
        $('#myprojects').fadeOut(1500);
        $('.projects').fadeOut(1500);           
        $('.square').attr('href', '#');                         
        $(".activenone").addClass('active');
        $(".active").removeClass('activenone'); 
        visible = false;
    });

        $('#cubefour3').click(function(){
        if (visible == false) {
            $('#myprojects').fadeIn(1500);
            $('#projectme').fadeIn(1500);
            $('.square').removeAttr("href");
            $(".active").addClass('activenone');
            $(".activenone").removeClass('active'); 
            visible = true;
        }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it working :)

I had applyed a transformation to each of the 6 sides in the cube in other to make it appear like 3d, like e.g. so:

```
.face:nth-child(6) { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(175px); 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(175px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(175px);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(175px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(175px);
}
```

The translateZ somehow overruled the div I had placed on top of it, so the links didn't work. (I have no explanation of this though). I then applyed a transformation on the new div, like so:

```
.projects {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(275px); 
    -moz-transform: translateZ(275px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(275px);
    -o-transform:translateZ(275px);
    transform: translateZ(275px);
}
```

Amazingly it seems to be working now :)